# How to Calculate Sample Size Requirements for Quasi-Poisson / Negative Binomial AB Test in R

Tags: r, sample-size, negative-binomial-distribution, quasi-likelihood

I'm doing an AB test of two conditions, where the success metric is looking for an increase in the number of users taking a particular action each day. The variance is hugely larger than the mean, from experience with past tests using this metric (ie. >200x the mean), so a quasi Poisson or negative binomial test is required.

I know the expected variance, mean per day, and level of change I would like to be sensitive to at the 0.95 significance level. How do I calculate the run time/sample size required, preferably in R?

Comment: Are the observations also clearly larger than 0? If so, it _might_ be possible to take the logs and treat the observations as approximately normal.